# Trying to move image up and down in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Essentially I am making a game where there is an image that has to move up and down acting as an obstacle for the player but for some reason it is just not working with the image. I tested it out with just a regular rectangle but it is having a problem with moving an image up and down. Here is the code:

```
sy_move = 2
sx_move = 2

def movesmasher():
    global sy_move 
    canvas.move(imgsmasher,sy_move, 0)
    pos = canvas.coords(imgsmasher)
    top_y = pos[1]
    bottom_y = pos[3]
    if top_y <= 0:
        sy_move = -sy_move
    elif bottom_y >= canvas_height-5:
        sy_move = -sy_move



image16= tkinter.PhotoImage(file="backround\\smasher.png")
smasherimg = image16.subsample(2,2)
imgsmasher = canvas.create_image(450,150, anchor=tkinter.SW, image=smasherimg)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. `canvas.move(imgsmasher, sy_move, 0)` will move the image horizontally, not vertically.  Use `canvas.move(imgsmasher, 0, sy_move)` instead;
2. `canvas.coords(...)` returns `(x, y)`, so `pos[3]` will raise exception. Use `canvas.bbox(...)` instead.

Updated `movesmasher()`:

```py
def movesmasher():
    global sy_move
    canvas.move(imgsmasher, 0, sy_move)
    pos = canvas.bbox(imgsmasher) # use bbox() instead of coords()
    top_y = pos[1]
    bottom_y = pos[3]
    if top_y <= 0 or bottom_y >= canvas_height-5:
        sy_move = -sy_move
```